# C Bit Operation Logic (bitAnd)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

**Background:**

I stumbled across bitwise operators in C [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html), and now I am trying to learn more about them. I searched around for exercises and came across [this](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~wms128/bits.c).

However, I'm having trouble understanding the first one "bitAnd."

The code reads:

```
/* 
 * bitAnd - x&y using only ~ and | 
 *   Example: bitAnd(6, 5) = 4
 *   Legal ops: ~ |
 *   Max ops: 8
 *   Rating: 1
 */
int bitAnd(int x, int y) {
       /* NOR Equivelent of AND */
  return ~(~x | ~y);

}
```

**Question:**

Now, I thought that the pipe ( | ) means "or." So, why do we need ~x and ~y? Can't we just say something like:

```
int bitAnd(int x, int y) {
    int or = x | y; //something is one number or the other
    int and = ~or; // not or is the same as and
    return and;
}
```

I wrote and ran the second code sample for myself (I have a main function to run it). I get -8 as the answer, but with values 6 and 5, you should get 4. 
If you have something for "or" (the pipe operator) and "and" is just the opposite or, why do we need to use "~" on each value before we calculate ~and?

**Some extra information/thoughts:**

I understand that "~" flips all the bits in the value. "Or" copies the bit from either value into the other if it exists (I learned that from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_bits_manipulation.htm)). So, if I have:

6 = 00000110 
and 
5 = 00000101
I should get 0000111.

I only mention that to show what knowledge I have of some of the operations in case my understanding of those are wrong as well.

Comment: Check out [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Your bit algebra at the end of the question is correct; if you apply it to _and_ the same way you did to _or_, you'll probably see why you were incorrect in thinking that "not or is the same as and".

Comment: I've written an article on this matter, check it out. http://ddacot.com/boolean-algebras-and-bit-level-operations-in-c .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typical logic gates knowledge. The equivalent of an AND gate is NOT of a NOR b.

Let's see what happens. Suppose you have values as such:

```
a = 00111 => 3
b = 01001 => 9

a AND b = 00001 => 1
```

This is what we expect. Let's run it through your shared method, the first one:

```
~a = 11000 => 24
~b = 10110 => 22
~a | ~b = 11110 => 30
~(~a | ~b) = 00001 => 1 as we expect.
```

Now, let's run your second proposed method.

```
or = 01111 => 15
and = ~or = 10000 => 16.
```

Now you have a problem. Logically, what you do is this:

```
~(a | b) = ~a AND ~b.
```

Is it really true though?

```
~a = 11000 => 24
~b = 10110 => 22
~a AND ~b = 10000 => 16.
```

It agrees with what I said above, however, it's wrong as you can see. We want 1, not 16. The bitwise inverse "~" operator is distributive. It inverts the operations as well. So an "or" becomes an "and" and an "and" becomes an "or". I hope that clears it up.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That makes perfect sense. I didn't think to check it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you provided uses the de Morgan's rules, which say that `not (A and B) = not A or not B`. Since you need to compute `A and B`, you negate everything once more and you get:  `A and B = not (not (A and B)) = not (not A or not B)`.

Now, you can also think in terms of truth tables to see why this is true and why your claim isn't. I won't show everything in detail, but in your solution, `not (A of B)` when both A and B are 0, the result is 1, which is not consistent with the and operation.